# How to override css for img tag

Tags: html, css

Following were my css for `img`:

```
img {
    border: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important
}
```

At the bottom of the style, I override the specific `img` as:

```
.locals-list>img {
    height: 35px;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="eas-footer">
    <div class="wrap cfx">
        <h6 class="know-your-city" style="text-align: center;">Supported by</h6>
        <div class="locals-list">
           <a href="http://www.indonesia.travel" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn.goasean.com/assets/content/sponsors/_normal/logo_wonderful_indonesia_2014.png" alt="{title}" data-pin-nopin="true"></a>                   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, my new `height` changes is not taking place. I am still getting `height: auto !important`. Thanks!

Comment: It's b/c `!important` has the highest priority

Comment: add !important with height to your .locals-list > img styles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another height with **!important** (`height: 35px !important;`) at the end of the CSS will override the previous height.

Also i have changed `.locals-list>img` to `.locals-list img`. Refer below code.

```css
img {
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.locals-list img {
  height: 85px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="eas-footer">
  <div class="wrap cfx">
    <h6 class="know-your-city" style="text-align: center;">Supported by</h6>
    <div class="locals-list">
      <a href="http://www.indonesia.travel" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://cdn.goasean.com/assets/content/sponsors/_normal/logo_wonderful_indonesia_2014.png" alt="{title}" data-pin-nopin="true">
      </a>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this property `!important`

```
.locals-list>img {
    height: 35px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`!important` keyword takes precedence over other property values. So either remove `!important` from `height:auto` (better way) or add `!important` to `height: 35px;`.

Adding `!important` in CSS is not a good thing. You should use it only for specific purposes like:

```
.always-hide-this-no-matter-what {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Here's an good [article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) on CSS specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have height:auto **!important** so if you wanna override it you must using important like:

```
.locals-list>img {
    height: 35px !important;
}
```